# How to select data that have complete cases of a certain column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a data frame (`just.samples.with.shoulder.values`, say) contain only samples that have non-`NA` values. I've tried to accomplish this using the `complete.cases` function, but I imagine that I'm doing something wrong syntactically below:

```
data <- structure(list(Sample = 1:14, Head = c(1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Shoulders = c(13L, 14L, NA, 
18L, 10L, 24L, 53L, NA, 86L, 9L, 65L, 87L, 54L, 36L), Knees = c(1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), Toes = c(324L, 
5L, NA, NA, 5L, 67L, 785L, 42562L, 554L, 456L, 7L, NA, 54L, NA
)), .Names = c("Sample", "Head", "Shoulders", "Knees", "Toes"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

just.samples.with.shoulder.values <- data[complete.cases(data[,"Shoulders"])]
print(just.samples.with.shoulder.values)
```

I would also be interested to know whether some other route (using `subset()`, say) is a wiser idea. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If you use "[" with a single argument and no comma, it will be selecting columns rather than what you wanted which was rows. Just add a comma between the paren and the left square-bracket at the end of the line `...lders"]) , ]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try using `is.na`:

```
data[!is.na(data["Shoulders"]),]
   Sample Head Shoulders Knees Toes
1       1    1        13     1  324
2       2    0        14     1    5
4       4    1        18     1   NA
5       5    1        10     1    5
6       6    1        24     2   67
7       7    0        53     3  785
9       9    1        86     1  554
10     10    1         9    NA  456
11     11    1        65     2    7
12     12    1        87     3   NA
13     13    0        54     4   54
14     14    1        36     3   NA
```

Answer (score 21):

You can try `complete.cases` too which will return a logical vector which allow to subset the data by `Shoulders`

```
data[complete.cases(data$Shoulders), ] 
#    Sample Head Shoulders Knees Toes
#  1      1    1        13     1  324
#  2      2    0        14     1    5
#  4      4    1        18     1   NA
#  5      5    1        10     1    5
#  6      6    1        24     2   67
#  7      7    0        53     3  785
#  9      9    1        86     1  554
# 10     10    1         9    NA  456
# 11     11    1        65     2    7
# 12     12    1        87     3   NA
# 13     13    0        54     4   54
# 14     14    1        36     3   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between using is.na and complete.cases.
is.na will remove actual na values whereas the objective here is to only control for a variable not deal with missing values/na's those which could be legitimate data points